# Constructing Permutations from Transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm given the following sets of transpositions and asked to prove that any permutation can be written as a product of permutations from the given set in each case.

I've come up with the following answers and am **wondering whether they are valid**.

**Answers**:

**(a)** Given: Set of all transpositions.

*My answer*: Since any permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles and any cycle can be written as a product of transpositions, it follows that any permutation can be written as a product of transpositions.

**(b)** Given: { $ (1 ~ 2), (1 ~ 3), ..., (1 ~ n) $ }

*My answer*: Any transposition can be created in the following manner:

$ (i ~ j) = (1 ~ i) (1 ~ j) (1 ~ i) $ $\forall$ i , j $\in$ (1, 2, ..., n)

All $(1 ~ i)$ combinations $\forall$ i $\in$ (1, ..., n) are available from the given set

If we can make any transposition, we can make any permutation.

**(c)** Given: { $ (1 ~ 2), (2 ~ 3), ..., (n-1 ~ n) $ }

*My answer:*

Any transposition can be created in the following manner:

$(i ~ j) = (i ~ n)(n ~ j)(i ~ n)$   $\forall$ i,j $\in$ (1, 2, ..., n)

All possible $(i ~ n)(n ~ j)(i ~ n)$ combinations exist in the given set.

If we can make any transposition, we can make any permutation.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  How can you get $(in)(nj)$ from {$(12),(23),...,(n-1\,n)$}?

Comment: e.g. (13) = (12)(23)(12) [where i = 1, n = 2 and j = 3]  or (79) = (78)(89)(78) [where i = 7, n = 8, j = 9]